# Origen de la expresión "manga por hombro"

Tags: expresiones, historia

Tras un día cualquiera, los niños suelen acabar dejando el salón *manga por hombro*. El diccionario define la expresión como:

> [**andar** algo **manga por hombro**](https://dle.rae.es/manga)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Estar en gran abandono y desorden.

Esta expresión tiene ya sus años, puesto que aparece en textos en el CORDE en el siglo XVII, y aparece también en el *Autoridades* de 1734:

> Andar *manga* por hombro. Phrase con que se dá à entender el descuido de algunas casas, donde todo anda sin regla, concierto ni proporcion.

Lo que me gustaría saber es de dónde viene la expresión. Mi idea original es que cuando algo está en un estado de gran desorden, si se quiere ordenar hay que hacer un esfuerzo, lo que suele acarrear el [arremangarse](https://dle.rae.es/arremangar) al entrar en calor. Si te arremangas tanto que la manga te llega por el hombro, es que el esfuerzo para ordenar es tanto que te has tenido que arremangar hasta donde no podías más. De ahí que se diga que algo está *manga por hombro* cuando está muy desordenado.

¿Es este el verdadero origen de la expresión? ¿Hay otras teorías? ¿Se refiere tal vez *manga* a otra de sus acepciones? ¿Hay algún documento donde se refleje este (u otro) posible origen de la expresión?

Comment: Quisiste decir Algunas cosas?

Comment: @WalterMitty no, a mí también me sonó raro pero lo comprobé varias veces y en el _Autoridades_ pone "algunas casas". Y es así, se refiere al desorden que se encuentra dentro de las viviendas.

Comment: También se me ocurre: si tienes la manga por hombro, tienes la ropa desordenada.  Si la casa está manga por hombro, está desordenada.  Pero no sé, en realidad.

Comment: Aunque la suposición es buena, y sin tener ninguna referencia fehaciente, siempre lo he entendido más en términos de sastrería. Si se corta mal una manga puede quedar corta -dicho exageradamente a la altura del hombro- o despegada del hombro.

Answer (score 1):

"Estar manga por hombro" viene de imaginarse la unión de un hombro con una manga de una chaqueta, donde la unión está hecha en el puño de la manga, es decir, al revés.

Se refiere, efectivamente, a cuando todo está desordenado o es un caos absoluto.

Te adjunto una página donde puedes ver de dónde viene: [Manga por hombro](https://expresionesyrefranes.com/2007/05/15/manga-por-hombro/).

Comment: No parece muy fiable la referencia ni la explicación. La manga es el trozo que va del hombro al puño, nada en la expresión indica que la manga esté al revés. Nótese que Charlie pregunta por el origen, lo cual implica cuando se empezó a usar y porqué, no por el significado. Su explicación alrededor de arremangarse parece más plausible.